# Magento 2 : Where I put my css?

Tags: theme, css, less, third-party-module, magento-2.1.7

I have installed magento 2.1.7 with custom theme. Now I want to add a custom css file for modifying theme css.

In that case what's the best practice to add css file.

1. Create a .less file and include it
2. Create a .css file and include
   it in layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using below code in your layout:

```
<head>
    <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/custom.css"/>
</head>
```

You have to delete folders

> pub/static
>
> var/

**create custom.less**
In custom.less file file import all less files as per your requirment.

```
magento\dev\tools\grunt\configs\theme.js
```

open theme.js file and add your less file under the theme
    Make sure don't give extensions when you add a file.

**For Example**

```
alive: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Alive/alivetheme',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/custom'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

deploy static content using command:  `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

check you css changes.

Comment: Which is the best method, CSS or LESS ?

Comment: Less is good way